# does socket.h's recvfrom() function recieve individual packets?

Tags: sockets, unix

The [man page for recvfrom](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=recv&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%207.0-RELEASE) summarizes its behavior as "receive a message from a socket". If the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_DGRAM, is "message" synonymous with "packet"? If not, how does it differ?

Comment: Stream sockets do not have messages, so the API cannot possibly read a message. TCP just does not have message boundaries.

Comment: No message boundaries -- I guess that's why they're called stream sockets. However, the man page uses the word "message" all over the place. Assuming recvfrom works on stream sockets, what is the "message" that the man page refers to?

Comment: Why are you asking this in the first place? Use `recv` for TCP. `recvfrom` is made for message-oriented protocols.

Comment: Trying to understand if there's a 1-1 correspondence between what's sent in a packet and what's accessed by recv. Looks to me like there isn't, that recv may access the contents of multiple packets.

Comment: Yes, the usage of the word `message` is confusing on that page. Network packets and `recv()` results do not usually have a 1-to-1 relation, but it depends on the underlying transport and configuration (buffer sizes, Nagle, message size, throughput, protocol, ...) and _can in fact_ be promised by the underlying protocol (see UDP).

Comment: @CodeCaster there is a 1-to-1 relationship between datagrams and `recv()` results for UDP sockets. And 1 datagram equals 1 packet as long as it doesn't get fragmented. Confusion only happens if you think the full text of the recvfrom man page should somehow apply to a type of socket that it wasn't meant to be used with.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was `recvfrom` works on stream sockets just because there's no reason to ban it. As in the famous quote:

> "Unix was not designed to stop its users from doing stupid things, as that would also stop them from doing clever things." – Doug Gwyn

If it did what I expected it to do, you could use it like a combination `read()` and `getpeername()` since it returns the sender's address. That might be considered clever.

But then I tried it on Linux, and it didn't work that way. The source address buffer was unchanged and the length indicator was set to 0.

So now I'm not sure what to say except don't use it on stream sockets. It's not meant for them.

**ADDENDUM**: And no, even in my wildest dreams I wouldn't have expected it to give you access to packet boundaries in a TCP stream. Data that has been put through the tcp receiving mechanism simply isn't made of packets anymore.

Comment: _"The recv() call is normally used only on a connected socket [...] and is identical to recvfrom() with a NULL src_addr argument."_

Comment: What's your point, @CodeCaster? I don't think anyone here is unclear on the relationship between `recv` and `recvfrom`.

Comment: It's about whether `recv()` and `recvfrom()` are interchangeable, which I commented on with what the `recv()` manual explicitly says about that. Granted, I don't know if OP specifically means `recvfrom()` in his question, as `recv()` is documented on the same page.

Comment: One of the man pages I found suggested that recv could potentially be removed in the future, since it's identical to recvfrom() with a NULL src_addr argument. Had I not seen that, I would have asked the question with recv. Didn't mean to confuse things.

Comment: If recvfrom() returned zero it meant that the peer has disconnected. The chances of recv() being removed in the future are precisely zero. I doubt that you really read anything of the sort.